# Dynamically adding builtin methods to point to a property's built-ins

Tags: python, partial-application

I have a couple classes and a function:

```
from functools import partial 

def fn(other, self, name):
    print(f"calling {name} with {other}")
    func =  getattr(self.a, name)
    return func(other)

class A:

    def __add__(self, other):
        return 9

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return 7

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return 8

class B:

    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a

        for name  in ['add', 'sub']:
            name = f"__{name}__"
            p = partial(fn, self=self,name=name)
            setattr(self, name, p)
            p.__name__ = name
```

I want to be able to use the forward the magic methods to an existing property.  I don't want to inherit the class because I don't want all the builtins. just a couple. For instance I might want to use multiply from a different class.  I'm trying to avoid coding like this:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    self.a.__add__(other)
```

using the above code I receive the following:

```
>>> b = B(A())
>>> b + 3
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-fa904b7bb783> in <module>
----> 1 b + 3
      2 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'B' and 'int'
>>> b.__add__(3)
calling __add__ with 3
9
```

Maybe I'm missing something simple but I can't find a way to dynamically add the builtin function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem to get around is that magic methods like `__add__` are looked up on the class, not on the object itself; otherwise you could just write `self.__add__ = a.__add__` in the `__init__` method. To get around this, we need to declare methods on the class `B`, not on individual instances of it.

The function `delegate` defined below works by adding a method to the `B` class. This method takes `self` which will be a `B` instance, so it has to dynamically load the `a` attribute and then its `__add__` method.

```py
class A:
    def __add__(self, other):
        return 9
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return 7
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return 8

class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

def delegate(cls, attr_name, method_name):
    def delegated(self, *vargs, **kwargs):
        a = getattr(self, attr_name)
        m = getattr(a, method_name)
        return m(*vargs, **kwargs)
    setattr(cls, method_name, delegated)

delegate(B, 'a', '__add__')
delegate(B, 'a', '__sub__')
```

Example:

```py
>>> b = B(A())
>>> b + 3
9
>>> b - 4
8
```

Answer (score 2):

Proxying `__dunder__` methods is tricky. I would use a descriptor object, which will work much more cleanly with the potential arcana of attribute access than other approaches.

```
class Proxy:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.attr = name
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        try:
            proxy = obj._proxy
        except AttributeError:
            raise AttributeError('tried to access proxy field on object with no _proxy')
        return getattr(proxy, self.attr)

class A:

    def __add__(self, other):
        return 9

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return 7

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return 8

class B:

    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a
        self._proxy = self.a
    __add__ = Proxy()
    __sub__ = Proxy()

b = B(A())
```

An example in the ipython repl:

```
In [6]: b = B(A())

In [7]: b + b
Out[7]: 9

In [8]: b - b
Out[8]: 8

In [9]: b * b
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-cb34cccc83f5> in <module>
----> 1 b * b

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'B' and 'B'
```

If you wanted to expand on this approach, `Proxy` could take a fieldname from which it proxies off of, so you could have something like:

```
class Proxy:
    def __init__(self, proxy_field):
        self.prox_field = proxy_field
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.attr = name
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        try:
            proxy = getattr(obj, self.proxy_field)
        except AttributeError:
            raise AttributeError(f'tried to access proxy field on object with no {self.proxy_field} attribute')
        return getattr(proxy, self.attr)

class B:

    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar

    __add__ = Proxy('foo')
    __sub__ = Proxy('bar')
```